# Structured Data: Nesting Triangles using structs and calculating

Tags: c++

Problem Description:write the code of a function which takes a triangle as input and returns its area. You are also expected to figure out how to access the data, by understanding the abstract data types defined.You may use any method to compute the area from the vertices

You are required to write a function:

Function Name : **cal_area**

This function has 1 parameter

triangle aTriangle:  It contains the 3 vertices of the triangle in x-y plane. You are expected to figure out how to access the data. 
The function should do the following

It should return the area of the triangle "aTriangle" as a float.

Well this is the question
i need to fill the following

```
//-----Include required headers here-----
#include <iostream.h>
#include <cmath>
//-----End of headers-----

//-----Don't change/delete structs-----
struct vertex{
float x;
float y;
};

struct triangle{
vertex vertices[3];
};
struct LineSegment
{
  Point endPoint1;
  Point endPoint2; 
}; 
//-----Structs end here


//-----Add new functions here(if any)-----
double eval (LineSegment line, Point p)
{
 Point p_a = p - line.endPoint1;
 Point l_dir = line.EndPoint2 - line.EndPoint1;

  return p_a.x * l_dir.y - p_a.y * l_dir.x;
 }
  void makeTriangleCounterclockwise(Triangle & t)
  {
   LineSegment ab = {t.vertices[1], t.vertices[0]};
   if ( eval(ab,t.vertices[2]) < 0.0) {

    swap(t.vertices[0],t.vertices[1]);
    }
    }

    //-----New functions end here-----

      float cal_area(triangle aTriangle) {
    //Write your solution below this line


     return (-1);
     //Dont write below this line
     }
```

i tried to write some fuction but went wrong 
pls help

Comment: What's the problem? Accessing the coordinates or computing the area from them? (You should be able to find the solution to the latter in any highschool-level maths book.)

Comment: I like the "you are to figure out" and "understanding". I suggest you start there.

Comment: 'i tried to write some fuction' - please show this attempt,

Comment: I suggest you stick to the `float` type given and not use `double eval()` and also to be careful of the case of C variables: the struct member `EndPoint1` should be `endPoint1`.

Comment: Did you literally copy/paste this from an assignment you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you’re trying to do is this:

```
float cal_area(triangle aTriangle) {
   float Area;

   Area = (aTriangle.vertices[1].x - aTriangle.vertices[0].x) *
          (aTriangle.vertices[2].y - aTriangle.vertices[1].y) -
          (aTriangle.vertices[1].y - aTriangle.vertices[0].y) *
          (aTriangle.vertices[2].x - aTriangle.vertices[1].x);

   if (Area < 0.0f) {
      return -Area / 2.0f;
   } else {
      return Area / 2.0f;
   }
}
```